# Disable collection pre-request script at request level

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a test collection in postman. I have a pre-request script to be run at the Collection level, but there are specific requests in the collection where I'd like the pre-request script not to run.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

You cannot do it, but as a workaround just add a condition for collection script like:

```js
if (pm.info.requestName !== "the request you want to skip") {

}
```

If you want to do it dynamically, then you have to do it from the request running before the request you want to skip:

---

For example:

In request 1:

```js
pm.variable.set("skip", true) // to skip request 2
```

in request 2:

```js
pm.variable.set("skip", false ) // to ensure remaining requests don't skip collection script
```

And in collection add

```js
if (!pm.variable.get("skip")) {
    //then execute
}
```

Comment: The condition should refer to `pm.info.requestName`, not `pm.info.request`, but the logic is still sound and I found this answer solved the problem for me.

Comment: Dynamically it does not work because collection pre-request script is run first - before the request script itself, so the variable is undefined.